# AttributeError: module 'cirq_google' has no attribute 'Foxtail'

Tags: programming, cirq

I have installed `cirq` in my anaconda environment by using the command:
`pip install cirq`

When I ran the code below to print the topology of Google Sycamore device:

```
import cirq_google
print(cirq_google.Sycamore)
```

It gave the following output.

```
                                             (0, 5)───(0, 6)
                                             │        │
                                             │        │
                                    (1, 4)───(1, 5)───(1, 6)───(1, 7)
                                    │        │        │        │
                                    │        │        │        │
                           (2, 3)───(2, 4)───(2, 5)───(2, 6)───(2, 7)───(2, 8)
                           │        │        │        │        │        │
                           │        │        │        │        │        │
                  (3, 2)───(3, 3)───(3, 4)───(3, 5)───(3, 6)───(3, 7)───(3, 8)───(3, 9)
                  │        │        │        │        │        │        │        │
                  │        │        │        │        │        │        │        │
         (4, 1)───(4, 2)───(4, 3)───(4, 4)───(4, 5)───(4, 6)───(4, 7)───(4, 8)───(4, 9)
         │        │        │        │        │        │        │        │
         │        │        │        │        │        │        │        │
(5, 0)───(5, 1)───(5, 2)───(5, 3)───(5, 4)───(5, 5)───(5, 6)───(5, 7)───(5, 8)
         │        │        │        │        │        │        │
         │        │        │        │        │        │        │
         (6, 1)───(6, 2)───(6, 3)───(6, 4)───(6, 5)───(6, 6)───(6, 7)
                  │        │        │        │        │
                  │        │        │        │        │
                  (7, 2)───(7, 3)───(7, 4)───(7, 5)───(7, 6)
                           │        │        │
                           │        │        │
                           (8, 3)───(8, 4)───(8, 5)
                                    │
                                    │
                                    (9, 4)
```

**But** when I tried to run for Google Foxtail device:

```
print(cirq_google.Foxtail)
```

The following error occurs-
`AttributeError: module 'cirq_google' has no attribute 'Foxtail'`

Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cirq_google.Foxtail` seems to have been deprecated with the `XmonDevices` as of v0.15.0 in June 2022.

See PR: https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/pull/5483

I opened a Cirq issue bringing light to the Foxtail device still being referenced a couple times in their docs: https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/issues/6111