# Foxtail, Bristlecone, etc not being recognized

Tags: bristlecone

for some reason `cirq_google` is not quite picking up on `Foxtail` and `Bristlecone` .

I just installed `cirq` and `cirq_google` today (7/25/2023), and for some reason my code with `Foxtail` is not being picked up. Here is the code I have right now:

```
import cirq
import cirq_google

circuit = cirq.Circuit()
(q0, q1) = cirq.LineQubit.range(2)

circuit.append([cirq.H(q0), cirq.CNOT(q0, q1)])
circuit.append([cirq.measure(q0), cirq.measure(q1)])

sim = cirq.Simulator()
results = sim.run(circuit, repetitions=10)
print(results)
print()
print(cirq_google.Foxtail)
```

I previously had code that was using `Bristlecone`, but I have since modified my code.

If someone can please help me out, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/32785/13991

Answer (score 0):

`cirq_google.Foxtail` and `cirq_google.Bristlecone` have been [deprecated](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/pull/5483). Use `cirq_google.Sycamore` or `cirq_google.Sycamore23` instead.